# Identifying password encryption

Tags: passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

We are trying to test whether a password is encrypted on submission of a form. We are attempting to use Fiddler, although have not proved yet that it is encrypted on submission and cannot be intercepted.

We can prove that once stored in the third-party application it is encrypted, although we know that the application can encrypt on receipt.

How can I check that it is encrypting on form submission, other than by checking the code?

Answer (score 1):

Passwords should be encrypted when being sent between the browser and the server. This should be done using SSL which browsers have built in support for. You can recognise when SSL is in use and properly configured because:

- The URL will start with `https:` not `http:`
- The browser will show some indicator

  - Chrome, for example, will display a padlock next to the URL
  - Clicking on the padlock and then examining the Connection tab will tell you more about the encryption that is in use

---

Once the password is on the server, it shouldn't be subject to two-way encryption. It should be stored using a [one-way cryptographic hash](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).